# Lambda expression in cython function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, cython

I want to use lambda expression with cython but it is not working with cpdef. The error says that it is not yet supported, but [cython changeleg](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/changes.html) says that lambda expressions are supported.

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

cdef foo():
    a = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
    b = sorted(a, key = lambda x: x%np.pi)   #Compiles
    return(b)

cpdef goo():
    a = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
    b = sorted(a)    #Compiles
    return(b)

cpdef hoo():
    a = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
    b = sorted(a, key = lambda x: x%np.pi)   #Compile time error
    return(b)
```

---

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cpdef goo():
    a = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
    b = sorted(a) 
    return(b)

cpdef hoo():
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/********/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_63378538fa4250ed3135e0289d6af7a0.pyx:14:6: closures inside cpdef functions not yet supported
```

Is it indeed the case that lambda expressions are not supported or am I missing something?

Python version 3.5.5; Cython version: 0.24

Comment: I can only see "Closures are fully supported for Python functions" and "Lambda expressions are supported in class bodies and at the module level" nothing about `cpdef`s.

Comment: However, it would be intersting to know what is the problem with `cpdef`  because `def`  and `cdef` don't seem to have a problem with lambdas

Comment: I assumed that when they say that it is supported at the module level then it imply that it is supported in functions. But, yes, that might not be the case.

Comment: @ead I would interpret "Cython supports inner functions and lambda expressions." as OP did, however it is vague if you consider the previous sentence (of the same point).

Comment: This looks like it should be [a bug report](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues) more than a question.

Answer (score 2):

This only about closures inside cpdef methods. If you do not define any function inside cpdef function, i.e closures, this would work. Lambda expression is just a functions, but with specific syntax. Try this.

```
def sort_key(x):
   return x%np.pi

cpdef hoo():
   a = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
   b = sorted(a, key = sort_key)
   return(b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not what I want.